# Convert value to float using asType() numpy

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I have the following code

```
trainX.append(x)
labelY.append([personData.isPerson,personData.isntPerson,personData.xmin,personData.ymin,personData.xmax,personData.ymax])
```

Where x is image loaded using

```
x = cv2.imread(PATH_TO_IMG + personData.path,3)
```

However i want both x and array passed to labelY to be stored as `float32`

I have tried following

```
trainX = np.array(trainX).asType("float32")
labelY = np.array(labelY).asType("float32")
```

or even

```
labelY.append([personData.isPerson,personData.isntPerson,personData.xmin,personData.ymin,personData.xmax,personData.ymax].asType("float32"))
```

neither of them works. What is the right way to convert the value into float?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `.astype(float)` ?

Comment: it complains about not having attribute asType or astype tried both

Comment: `np.array(trainX).astype(float)`

Comment: If `astype` doesn't work then you don't have an array.

Answer (score 0):

List's have an `append` method, numpy arrays do not.

```
alist.append(1)
```

modifies `alist` in-place, and returns nothing (actually `None`).  `None` does not have a `astype` method.

```
In [19]: alist=[]
In [20]: x = alist.append(1)
In [21]: x    # None
In [22]: alist
Out[22]: [1]
In [23]: alist.append(2).astype('float')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-7123155bd568> in <module>()
----> 1 alist.append(2).astype('float')

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'astype'
In [24]: alist
Out[24]: [1, 2]
```

a list doesn't have an `astype` method either:

```
In [25]: alist.astype(float)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-d0fc5f951ddf> in <module>()
----> 1 alist.astype(float)

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'astype'
```

I can turn a list into an array:

```
In [26]: np.array(alist).astype(float)
Out[26]: array([1., 2.])
```

If

```
trainX = np.array(trainX).asType("float32")
```

does not work, then you need to tell us error.  `DOES NOT WORK` is not a useful way of describing a problem!

---

Here's an example of an array for which `astype` does not work:

```
In [27]: alist.append([3,4])
In [28]: alist
Out[28]: [1, 2, [3, 4]]
In [29]: np.array(alist)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-7512d762195a> in <module>()
----> 1 np.array(alist)

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
In [30]: np.array(alist,object)
Out[30]: array([1, 2, list([3, 4])], dtype=object)
In [31]: _.astype(float)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-b12cc607d111> in <module>()
----> 1 _.astype(float)

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Pay attention to the error message and to the dtype.